# Enabling CURL for Codeception

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, codeception

I have an issue when executing tests with Codeception on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. When I execute a test I get an error saying that CURL extension is not installed, but it is. 
This is the error message I get:

```
 Codeception requires CURL extension installed to make tests run          
 If you are not sure, how to install CURL, please refer to 
 StackOverflow  

 Notice: PHP for Apache/Nginx and CLI can have different php.ini 
 files.   
 Please make sure that your PHP you run from console has CURL enabled.
```

I enabled curl extension in php.ini file, but the result stays the same.
I'll be grateful for any help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that you are using more then one PHP Version on the same system.

Try in command line `php -m |grep curl`. When the output is empty the current php has no curl extension installed. If the output is "curl", then it is and you can call codeception with php infront so you can be sure the php in the path is used.

`php codecept run`

And please be sure be up-to-date for codeception version.